# Atualizar Page após PopAsync no XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, xaml, xamarin-forms

Tenho uma página com a lista de despesas contém as informações da viagem como Descrição valor bruto, despesas e total líquido e ainda uma lista com as despesas de minha viagem.
O problema é que quando vou Editar ou criar uma nova despesa, e dou o comando PopAsync para voltar para Lista de Despesas, é carregado a lista de despesas atualizada e também os valores atualizados da viagem, mas é atualizado apenas o ListView e as informações passadas pelo BindContext = viagem não são atualizadas.
Alguem tem uma ideia de como atualizar estas informações ao voltar para a pagina anterior?

```
    Viagem _viagem;
    Movimento _movimento;
    ObservableCollection<Despesa> _listaDespesa;

    public ListaDespesaViagemPage (Viagem viagem, Movimento movimento)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        _viagem = viagem;
        _movimento = movimento;
    }

    private void carregarLista()
    {
        BindingContext = _viagem;
        DespesaDal despesaDal = new DespesaDal();
        _listaDespesa = new ObservableCollection<Despesa>(despesaDal.GetDespesasViagem(_viagem.ViagemId));
        ltvDespesas.ItemsSource = _listaDespesa;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        carregarLista();
    }
```

[Resolução]

Usei uma outra abordagem que acabou resolvendo.
Ao invés de `BindingContext = _viagem` e no XAML ter `Text="{Binding Data}"` eu nomeei o label  `x:Name="lblData"` e no evento `OnAppearing` eu passei a informação para o label especifico  `lblData.Text =  _viagem.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Novo Código ficou:

**C#**

```
    private void carregarTela()
    {
        lblDescricao.Text = _viagem.Descricao;
        lblData.Text =  _viagem.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        lblValorBruto.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", _viagem.Valor);
        lblDespesas.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", _viagem.ValorDespesas);
        lblLiquido.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", _viagem.Liquido);

        DespesaDal despesaDal = new DespesaDal();
        _listaDespesa = new ObservableCollection<Despesa>(despesaDal.GetDespesasViagem(_viagem.ViagemId));
        ltvDespesas.ItemsSource = _listaDespesa;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        carregarTela();
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Label x:Name="lblDescricao"/>
<Label x:Name="lblData"/>
<Label x:Name="lblValorBruto" />
<Label x:Name="lblDespesas"/>
<Label x:Name="lblLiquido"/>
```

Obrigado a todos...

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse problema algumas vezes, tente setar o ItemsSource para null antes de atribuir à lista:

```
private void carregarLista()
{
    BindingContext = _viagem;
    DespesaDal despesaDal = new DespesaDal();
    _listaDespesa = new ObservableCollection<Despesa>(despesaDal.GetDespesasViagem(_viagem.ViagemId));
    ltvDespesas.ItemsSource = null;
    ltvDespesas.ItemsSource = _listaDespesa;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Irei testar essa solução em outra tela com o mesmo problema, pois nessa resolvi usando outra abordagem...